# Disable TinyMCE in Keystone js

Tags: tinymce, keystonejs

Is there a way to completely disable the TinyMCE editor from Keystone js backend, leaving just a plain text field instead of the wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting WYSIWYG to false disabled the editor for me:

```
data: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: false }
```

Add the option to your model in Keystone.